# The emit function is invalid after sending the request

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code:

```
a.$emit('onsectioninfochange')  // valid
const res = await this.$axio.$get('/inquirysec/' + 'sectionDetails')
if (res.success) {
    a.$emit('onsectioninfochange') // invalid
}
```

While the `$emit` call works fine when placed before the request, it doesn't do anything when calling it after sending the request.

Why does this happen and how can I make sure the call to `$emit` works after sending the request, just as well as when called before it?

Comment: Here what do you mean by invalid?Are you getting any error?If so please add the description.

Comment: Valid means the emit event can be triggered normally， and invalid means it do nothing.

Comment: Have you tried adding console.log in if condition.Is your api returning success?

Comment: the res.success is true.I tried.

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: fiddle means what.

Comment: It is an online community for testing and showcasing user-created and collaborational HTML, CSS and JavaScript code snippets.Put your code over here https://jsfiddle.net so other people can check and help you.

Comment: @Riddhi Please do not ask for external code references. Stackoverflow has snippet functionality. Only refer to external code sites when that won't suffice.